# What does required_grad do in PyTorch? (Not requires_grad)

Tags: python, pytorch, backpropagation, resnet

I have been trying to carry out transfer learning on a multiclass classification task using resnet as my backbone.

In many tutorials, it was stated that it would be wise to try and train only the last layer (usually a fully connected layer) again, while freezing the other layers. The freezing would be done as so:

```
for param in model.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False
```

However, I just realized that all of my layers were actually **not freezed**, and while checking on my code I realized I had made a typo:

```
for param in model.parameters():
    param.required_grad = False
```

In a way that I wrote `required_grad` instead of `requires_grad`.

I can't seem to find information on `required_grad` - what it is, nor what it does. The only thing I found out was that it did not change the `requires_grad` flag, and that there is a separate `required_grad` flag which is set to False instead.

Can anyone explain what `required_grad` does? Have I been 'not freezing' my other layers all this time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, this was really silly.

```
for param in model.parameters():
    param.required_grad = False
```

In this case, a new 'required_grad' is created due to the typo I made.
For example, even the following wouldn't invoke an error:

```
for param in model.parameters():
    param.what_in_the_world = False
```

And all the parameters of the model would now have a `what_in_the_world` attribute.

I hope no one else wastes their time due to this.